# JQuery map filtering?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've copied and pasted a `list.js` file off of the internet. It's obtaining a list of files. However, I want to filter the files, so that the only files returned are those with the name `index.html`. I'm not familiar with Javascript nor jQuery, but I realize the change probably needs to occur within the first 1-9 lines. Any help would be awesome!

```
function getInfoFromS3Data(xml) {    
  var files = $.map(xml.find('Contents'), function(item) {    
    item = $(item);    
    return {    
      Key: item.find('Key').text(),    
      LastModified: item.find('LastModified').text(),    
      Size: bytesToHumanReadable(item.find('Size').text()),    
      Type: 'file'    
    }    
  });

  var directories = $.map(xml.find('CommonPrefixes'), function(item) {    
    item = $(item);    
    return {    
      Key: item.find('Prefix').text(),    
      LastModified: '',    
      Size: '0',    
      Type: 'directory'    
    }    
  });

  if ($(xml.find('IsTruncated')[0]).text() == 'true') {    
    var nextMarker = $(xml.find('NextMarker')[0]).text();    
  } else {    
    var nextMarker = null;    
  }

  return {    
    files: files,    
    directories: directories,    
    prefix: $(xml.find('Prefix')[0]).text(),    
    nextMarker: encodeURIComponent(nextMarker)    
  }    
}
```

Comment: Is `Key` the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to check the name of the file (presumably the `Key` in your example) matches what you require and return the object, or `null` if not so that the file is skipped. Try this:

```
var files = $.map(xml.find('Contents'), function(item) {    
  var item = $(item);   

  if (item.find('Key').text().toLowerCase() !== 'index.html')
    return null;

  return {    
    Key: item.find('Key').text(),    
    LastModified: item.find('LastModified').text(),    
    Size: bytesToHumanReadable(item.find('Size').text()),    
    Type: 'file'    
  }    
});
```